# Dependencies on Media class in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

I have a simple ModelAdmin, which defines a Media class and this class includes some JavaScript

```
class ExerciseAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = (
            'exercises/ck-editor-dynamic-init.js',
        )
```

I'd like to use `django.jQuery` in this script, but the problem is that when thi script is injected to the admin site `django.jQuery` is not initialized yet.
Here is my workaround, but it's ugly:

```
let loading = setInterval(function () {
  if (django.jQuery !== undefined) {
    loading = clearInterval(loading);
    (function ($) {
        $(document).on('formset:added', function newForm(event, row) {
            console.log(event);
        });
    })(django.jQuery);
  }
}, 100);
```

I can imagine, that this is not the best way how to do it. Can somebody suggest any better? Thanks

Comment: What if you include jQuery source also

Comment: Django's jQuery adds a couple useful methods/events. For example it fires `formset:added`. You don't have this in regular jQuery. Besides that, I don't want to load two jQuerys next to each other

Answer (score 1):

Adding `'jquery.init.js',` to your list should fix the problem:

```py
    class Media:
        js = (
            'admin/js/jquery.init.js',
            'exercises/ck-editor-dynamic-init.js',
        )
```